# React native IOS :axios/fetch request stuck with no error or no response on IOS only

Tags: ios, react-native, axios, fetch

Description:

sending a request with **Axios or fetch** in IOS not work and it doesn't matter if the API is `HTTPS` or `HTTP` 
no error reaches the catch or no response received 
also no errors, only warnings

```
2020-02-18 21:31:21.096 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.NetworkingQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:53] Sending `didReceiveNetworkResponse` with no listeners registered.
2020-02-18 21:31:21.100 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.NetworkingQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:53] Sending `didReceiveNetworkData` with no listeners registered.
2020-02-18 21:31:21.100 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.NetworkingQueue][RCTEventEmitter.m:53] Sending `didCompleteNetworkResponse` with no listeners registered.
```

this only happin with IOS , android works fine

React Native version:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.3
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 40.29 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.13.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.12.0 => 16.12.0
    react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

### Steps To Reproduce

1. just send any request to any API 
   2.

### Expected Results

get a result or even error from the API

### Snack, code example, screenshot, or link to a repository:

the app stuck here because I'm waiting for a result or error from the request
[image]

my simple function

```
export const checkAuth = (accessToken) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.google.com', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        // Accept: 'application/json',
        // Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    })
    const json = await response.json()
    const { error } = json

    if (error) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
  catch (error) {
    return false
  }
}
```

my info.plist 
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I believe that your problem is not the same as mine. Because the problem was that the API(backend) didn't support IPv6. I know it will be kind of weird. but this was the problem

Comment: OK. Thank you. Very weird.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, with `fetch` as well, no error, no response it's stuck on the `await` or never gets to then `then` block. But proxyman (seeing requests from app) shows the request was made. I'll circle back if I find a solution for others that are still stuck

Comment: @mswieboda I found a solution for me. For me the issue was a breaking change between `react-native@0.64.3` (works) and `0.67.1` (breaks).
The issue did not appear again in `react-native@0.68.2`.

Comment: @Robert thanks for sharing. I'm actually on `0.68.2`, and it was still happening. I'm not 100% positive, but I think it was an issue with a babel config for me https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/3100#issuecomment-962605244 `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` was causing an issue it seems